# How can I get notifications that a file is being read on OS X?

Tags: macos, notifications, filesystems, kernel, fsevents

I have a piece of software that works on Windows. The software has two components: file system minifilter driver that works in kernel mode and a user mode component that talks to the driver. Driver receives notifications on IO interrupt requests, such as [`IRP_MJ_READ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). A sample application that does this can be found on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/3528ffbb369fa0611aefd14c97bdd6ac5ee50c41/filesys/miniFilter/passThrough). This works for any user and most file systems supported by Windows.

I need to develop similar piece of software for OS X (desktop and server only). Things I looked at:

- [FSEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/)
- [Kernel Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH5-SW2)
- System call table API hooking/hijacking
- [kprobe](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt)
- [fanotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html)

My reservations are: FSEvents may not be very performant, as I need to monitor root `/` folder and any mounted devices. I have very limited understanding of kernel queues and syscalls API hijacking may make it very hard to port to different OS X versions and can cause conflicts with AV or OS protection (such as PaX hardening).

**Question:** how can I get notifications that a file in any (recursive) folder in root `/` is being read by any user on OS X?

Comment: another question for you:  do you intend for your app to be sandboxed or available on the Mac app store?

Comment: Not sure, whatever's easier and whatever will allow me to do this. I think AVs are available through the store and sandboxing probably won't allow me to do things I need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a kernel extension, [Kernel Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION10) provides the [File Operation Scope](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION10), allowing you to monitor the `KAUTH_FILEOP_OPEN`action for all vnodes.

The `KAUTH_FILEOP_OPEN`action will be called before access to all files, thus allowing you to monitor file access.

If you want more granularity of actions, the [VNode scope](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION11) provides a larger set of actions, including `KAUTH_VNODE_READ_DATA`, but be aware that this scope can be very noisy, triggering a very large number of actions at any one time.

Example code for such a kernel extension can be found in Singh's [Mac OS X Internals](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0134426541/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446729275&sr=1-1&keywords=mac%20os%20x%20internals)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the performance of FSEvents; if you use Spotlight and/or Time Machine, it's already running on your system. I'd be very surprised if there was a more efficient way to reimplement it from scratch. So if it meets your requirements in every other way, I'd go with that.

Comment: FSEvents does not provide me with Process Id (or process name) and User security identifier (or user name). Example I am after is: Bob reads a file in /tmp/banana with application bananareader.jar at 7:50 AM. I think FS events can only provide me with with /tmp/banana file was read at 7:50.